# How to reach at the next row (SQL)

Tags: sql, mysqli

How can I reach at the third row using SQL query? "qid" is the primary key here. I do not want to reach at the third row by counting the qid! Any generic method??

[image]

```
if (source == see_a_question_card__next_btn){
            ResultSet next = null;
            try {
                next = database_connection.statement.executeQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM questions");

                next.next();
                question= Integer.parseInt(next.getString(1));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want "question" variable with the next row number in the form of "qid".

Comment: Though the answer below is correct, I wonder why it would be necessary to ever identify a record by its position in the table.  The id is more correct.

Comment: I am using on e question at a time, Just as, Show me first question, than I add sql query it show me the next row and so on.
     
Whole table is relevent. Full table consists of questions. The one solution is that I iterate the cursor by using "qid" but it does not work if the question 3 is deleted with "qid=3" than how the cursor will reach at the forth row?

Answer (score 1):

Use `limit <offset>, <number of records to fetch>`

To get **only** the 3rd record use

```
select * from your_table
order by qid
limit 2, 1
```

to get all records **starting** from the 3rd one use

```
select * from your_table
order by qid
limit 2, 999999999
```

Comment: It is not generic in my scenario. I want to go to next row from the last row whatever it is, either 4 , 5 ,6. In this condition it is hardcode that "GO TO THIRD ROW."

Comment: You do that in your program logic.  Fetch all the relevant records. and the step through them in a loop.

Comment: I am using on e question at a time, Just as, Show me first question, than I add sql query it show me the next row and so on.

Comment: Whole table is relevent. Full table consists of questions. The one solution is that I iterate the cursor by using "qid" but it does not work if the question 3 is deleted with "qid=3" than how the cursor will reach at the forth row?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. If you select the whole table and then iterate through the whole result-set you should get any question. Could you proivde us the implementation of your iterator/cursor?

Comment: Code is now above under picture.